# Noise from laptop

Tags: fan, noise

I hope everybody is doing well. I have had this noise from my computer every `0 - 20 minutes for 2 days. it happened 1 time 1 month ago and sometimes it stops when I tap on the cooling fan side. Here's the sound I recorded:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1k8ocZ_ohbIIbRtcy6p280N34BheYbP/view?usp=sharing

I opened my laptop case and the cooling fan seems clean from the outside.
Any idea why this could happen?

Model: Dell latitude e7450

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to be certain from the sound, but it sounds a lot like the lubrication of the fan bearing has dried up. The possible fixes for this are:

- Replace the fan assembly
- Remove the fan assembly and relubricate the bearing

If you're not confident in your ability to do either of these, then you'll need to take it to a computer repair shop. In particular, the difficulty of the second option will depend on the design of the fan and how easy it is to gain access to the bearing. Some fans just have a sticker that can be peeled back and some drops of oil put into the hole, others require the impeller to be removed which can require some force and care needs to be taken not to break the fan blades.